# Problem with decimal property databinding in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a simple `Post` method on a Web API controller (ASP.NET Core 5.0) similar to the following:

```
[HttpPost("API_Path"]
public IActionResult DoSomething([FromBody] InputProps props)
{
   // do something with props 

   return Ok();
}
```

When my `InputProps` class has properties with `decimal` data type, i.e.

```
public class InputProps
{
    public decimal Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

the value passed is truncated to 2-digits after the decimal. This can be worked around by changing the data type to `double` instead of `decimal`, but it seems to me like this is a bug, unless someone knows of a way to make it work using the `decimal` type?

I say "bug" because the precision of the decimal type in .NET should permit 28-29 digits ([Floating-point numeric types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types)).

Comment: "the value passed is truncated to 2-digits after the decimal" How did you find it?

Comment: You can use the `[Display]` attribute's `DataFormatString` [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.dataformatstring?view=net-6.0) to change how textual values are converted to decimal.

Comment: I tried what @dia suggested: `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{N6}")] public decimal Prop1 { get; set; }` and it still truncates after 1/100 so that the string "0.012" is treated as "0.01".

Comment: @Serge, I'm debugging my "DoSomething" method.  The props.prop1 value is truncated, but the header in my browser debugger has the correct value.

Comment: @EricStimpson the only  important thing about it  is if it causes a wrong result or not ?

Comment: @Serge, I don't follow what you're saying.  It is the wrong result, because the value being posted has more significant digits than the value that the controller's function is receiving, so data precision is lost.  Switching data type to `double` "fixes" the issue, but I think the behavior for `decimal` datatype should be to keep all significant digits, or at least provide a clear way to specify how the value should be parsed.

Comment: @EricStimpson But where is it post from ?  can you post the relevant parts of view too pls? I suspect that it was rounded somewhere on the way.

Comment: @Serge, I've tested using Swagger, Postman, and React.  I can say for certain that it is not an issue with the view layer because simply changing the datatype on the InputProps class is sufficient, and the view layer knows nothing of this class.

Comment: @EricStimpson You posted one property and think that somebody will be able to help you. You have to post all relevant code including all actions and views where this property  participating.

Comment: @EricStimpson Check db. I am sure that this column has 18.2 in your db.